# Why does this solution say the DFS have to run in reverse?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

Wouldn't it keep finding t if we start at s?

> Give a linear-time algorithm that takes as input a directed acyclic graph G = (V,E) and two vertices s and t, and returns the number of paths from s to t in G.

---

solution:

> The basic idea here is to start at vertex t, and use depth-first search in reverse direction until we reach vertex s. Each and maintains a counter which indicates the number of unique reverse paths found from vertex t.
>
> 1. Initialize counters to 0 for all vertices.
> 2. Start depth-first-search in reverse direction using vertex t as a root.
> 3. For each edge (u, y) examined in the breadth-first search. `Counter(v) = max{ Counter(v) + 1, Counter(v) + Counter(u) }`
> 4. Return Counter(s).

Comment: The question explicitly says start at t, not s.  And the point is t see how may unique reverse paths there are from t to s.

Comment: The quoted text first talks about DFS and then about BFS, so which is it? I don't think DFS would work in any direction, because you would always end up with `Counter(s)` being 1 (or 0).

Comment: And I don't see how would this work with BFS either.

Comment: john Weldon: I separated the question and the solution i found to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
(this is from http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/cond-mat/pdf/0308/0308217v1.pdf, Pg 5).

We will give weights to different vertices starting with s, based on the number of paths to the vertex from S and also set their distance based on the no of edges they are away from s.

1. Start with wt(S) = 1 and d(s) = 0;
2. Every vertex i adjacent to S is given weight = w(s) = 1 and d(i)  = (d) +1;
3. For each vertex j adjacent to one of these vertices and d(j) not yet defined, 
   if w(j) = 0, then assigned w(i)=w(j) /*that is assign the wt of parent to j*/
   else if d(j)=d(i) +1 , then w(j) = w(i) + 1.
4. Repeat step 3 till T is reached. The wt(t) will give the number of shortest paths from s to T.

Accordingly, the paper explains why this is linear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *need* to run the algorithm in reverse. You can count the solutions in linear time also with a forward search. I don't think the solution says that you *need* to do it in reverse, and you don't.

Both forward and reverse search are based on the same general identity, which is that

```
number-of-paths(s, t) =
  sum over nodes 'c' of any cut of the graph that separates s from t:
    number-of-paths(s, c) * number-of-paths(c, t)
```